# Sent BTC to BCC Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

In hopes of claiming BCC I sent BTC (Mycellium wallet) to a recently generated BCC wallet (Bitcoin.com). The transaction was confirmed, however, I don't see the BCC in my BCC wallet (or BTC in my BTC wallet!). How can I retrieve my BTC and BCC?

Comment: You can't send one currency to a wallet of another transaction. Unfortunately BCH and BTC use the same type of addresses, so this is an easy misunderstanding. You'll need to contact support for the wallet service the recover funds unfortunately, there is little we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Because BTC and BCC have the same address type, it this is an easy mistake to make. Try finding the mnemonic or seed used to restore your BCC wallet from bitcoin.com, and instead use it to generate the BTC version of your wallet. Not all wallets provide support for BTC and BCC; some online exchanges don't give users their mnemonic recovery and worse still, a lot of wallets implement BIP 39 mnemonic differently.

This is one of the problems with forks, having multiple chains causes confusion, and people lose their money.

Comment: I have the mnemonic for both wallets. I'm confused as to "instead use it to generate the BTC version of your wallet."